# Sending data with urlopen to django server

Tags: django, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to send a request to my django server.

I've tried the following:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/"
data = urlencode({"foo": "bar"}).encode()

urlopen(Request(url, data=data, method="POST"))
# Produces single GET request (status 200), data not received by django server

urlopen(url, data=data)
# Produces single GET request (status 200), data not received by django server

requests.post(url, data)
# Produces single GET request (status 200), data not received by django server
```

My django server is essentially this:

```
# api/urls.py:
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^test/', views.cache_input),
    # There are other urls here, but are called with "url/?param=value"
)


# api/views.py:
def cache_input(request):
    return HttpResponse(b"ok")
    # All methods above receive b"ok"
```

Is there something I'm missing? I can't seem to find data in django's request variable. I tried to read data from every request's attribute. None of them contain "foo" or "bar".

Comment: Please show the URL, your Django view and urlconf, and explain how you are verifying that the data is not received.

Comment: I still don't see how you're verifying that the data is not received, or what the request method is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I looked in request.POST, request.GET, request.body, even in request.META, request.FILES, etc.